# code button inflater

Tags: android, layout, button, android-activity

I have this main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings4:
            mainactivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_settings1:
            ipallilos();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_settings2:
            rithmisi();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_settings3:
            sxetika();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

private void mainactivity() {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Επιστροφή στην Αρχική Σελίδα", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private void rithmisi() {
    setContentView(R.layout.rithmisis);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading Settings", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void ipallilos() {
    setContentView(R.layout.ipallilos);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading Staff", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void sxetika() {
    //anoigma menou efarmogis
    setContentView(R.layout.sxetikame);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading about Software", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
         //moveTaskToBack(true);
         super.onBackPressed();
         return true;
     }

     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }




public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
           // case 1:
              //  return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        switch (args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){

        case 1: 
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.paraggeleialayout, container, false);


        case 2:
             return inflater.inflate(R.layout.trapezia, container, false);

    }

        return getView();

}





    }
}
```

I have at .paraggeleialayout  some buttons.
I have try to add setOnClickListener to my button to open an other class but it does not
work. Here is my paraggeleia class.

```
public class paraggeleia extends Activity {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.paraggeleialayout);
              TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
                 Button bTutorial = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button51);
                text.setText(R.string.paraggeleia);
           bTutorial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
             finish();
            }
        });
    }





    @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
             super.onBackPressed();
             return true;
         }

         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }
}
```

Comment: You never actually start the `paraggeleia` Activity and you inflate the layout in a Fragment too, which doesn't magically give the buttons listeners. Mind clarifying what you want to do?

Comment: I want to start from palaggeleia button51 the activity paraggelialayout.

Comment: But `button51` is part of the Activity you're trying to launch.

Comment: No button51 is part of paraggeleia and i try to start paraggeleialayout.

Comment: Your layout != the Activity. The same layout may be part of 50 (random number) Activities all with different names.

Comment: Look i have 6 activity main, paraggeleia, paraggeleialayout, trapezia, arxiki, ippalilos.  the main activity have 2 activity, paraggelia and trapezia like playstore. slide scroll

Comment: `R.layout.activity_main` is a layout, not an Activity, it's just being used by the Activity `MainActivity`. You need to be clearer in your question, possibly draw a diagram or something because you aren't starting any activities right now with a button click. Same with `R.layout.trapezia` that's a layout, not an Activity

Comment: i am going to send you some photo.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1fcbeuq50uw8ydu/D5B3ZlR_hC

Comment: 1 and 2 is my main layout

Comment: and the blue button i want to press and go to the 4 photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think this is clearer now, so you want your ViewPager layout to launch the next Activity. You may want to do something like this:

```
case 1: 
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.paraggeleialayout, container, false);
       Button bTutorial = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button51);
           bTutorial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v){
           getActivity().startActivity(new Intent (getActivity(), paraggeleia.class));
            }
        });
return v;
```

However your `paraggeleia.class` as it stands contains the same layout (`R.layout.paraggeleialayout`) as the Fragment, so consider changing that Activity's layout to something else.

Comment: I take some error (Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity.)

Comment: Button bTutorial = (Button) _findViewById_(R.id.button51);

Comment: Sorry about that. Editing as we speak. Needs to be `v.findViewById()`